# Implementing a formula from a paper

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, summation

Is this:`Table[Exp[-((1250^2) dism11[[n, m]])/Sum[dism11[[i, j]], {i, n, 1250}, {j, m, 1250}]], {n, 1, 1250}, {m,1, 1250}]` a correct way to implement:

[image]

I am kinda confused with the summation formula used in the denominator inside the exponentiation. The formula comes from: https://kilthub.cmu.edu/articles/journal_contribution/Signal_Denoising_on_Graphs_via_Graph_Filtering/6469307

If it's the correct implementation then it's very slow and memory intensive.

`dism11` is the distance matrix of size `1250 X 1250`

Comment: It looks that the correct expression for `P[n,m]` is something like this: `Exp[-((1250^2) dism11[n, m])/  Sum[dism11[i, j], {i, 1, 1250}, {j, 1, 1250}]]`.

Comment: Does this mean that I can calculate the normalization (summation) only once and then use that inside the table?

Comment: Yes, I would do that, like `norM=Sum[dism11[i, j], {i, 1, 1250}, {j, 1, 1250}]` and once the factor `norM` has been calculated Mma already knows its value, and one can use it as a known parameter.

Comment: As @AlexeiBoulbitch points out, the paper's authors should have used different summation variables in the denominator instead of reusing $n$ and $m$. Judging from long experience I would not trust a paper that contains such mistakes, because the authors are not careful with formulas and therefore likely not careful with concepts. I'd recommend looking for another paper on the same topic that is written more carefully.

Comment: @Roman I agree. Even after implementing what they have in the paper, I do not get the result that they have shown in the paper. A simple formula gives me a better result than what they have in the paper. Maybe they used some trick which they didn't mention in the paper? or maybe I am just being too dumb?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Mathematica, it is best to use list processing instead of explicit looping over elements:

```
P = Exp[-d/Mean[Flatten[d]]];
```

where `d` is your `dism11`. Notice that the size of the matrix is implicit and we don't need to specify it: all operations are done over the entire matrix.

Even more Mathematica-like would be to use a [user-specific normalization operation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normalize.html):

```
P = Exp[-Normalize[d, Mean@*Flatten]]
```

Comment: Very Mathematika-like. Should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

You compute the same sum again and again. Instead precompute the sum

```
nmx=1250;
sum=Sum[dism11[[i, j]], {i, nmx}, {j,nmx}]/nmx^2;
```

Then evaluate your function

```
Table[Exp[- dism11[[n, m]]/sum], {n, nmx}, {m,nmx}]
```

Notice, this is translation of your formula, admittedly it is a bit ambiguous.